# How to embed a jquery slideshow in Ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

We are trying to create a slideshow for our site, http://www.mealnut.com. Something similar to what is on the http://www.airbnb.com. Is there any tutorial for the same! We are kind of newbie to this.

Answer (score 2):

Such a view logic should be JS work. Try one at http://themeflash.com/30-powerful-jquery-slideshow-sliders-plugins-and-tutorials/. Embed one of these on your rails or refer some code on your application.js.

These links would also detail the situation:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript